# Customize bottommost of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I am preparing a presentation consisting of 3 parts. After the title page and the outline page I'm starting part 1, once it's done part 2 etc.

I want the bottommost three parts to be My name, institute and part 1 when the presentation is part 1, part 2 when it's part 2 and similarly for part 3.

How can I achieve this? Apologies if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Please add a MWE that shows which theme you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use some theme which is based on the `infolines` outer theme, you could use this quick hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{names}
\title{text}
\institute{institute}

\AtBeginPart{\title{\insertpart}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\part{part 1}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\part{part 2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. It almost worked. Only that I had my title as the second item, but once I put \part{}, that replaces the title. Is there a way to keep the title in the second item and having the part as the third item. By items I'm refering to the three separated regions at the bottom of a slide.

Comment: @Fib1123 That's possible  by redefining the footline, but you still have not shown a MWE so I don't know which theme you use.

Comment: my bad. I'm using \usetheme{Madrid}.